# What is faster: more classes or unique class

Tags: css

I use the 2 ways but I prefer the first due to reuse code. some prefer one or other. But I would like to know if the load in big stylized pages is better in one way than the other.

1)

```
<style>
  .red{ color:red}
  .right25{ margin-right: 25px}
  .bold{ font-weight:bold}
</style>

<p class="red right25 bold">this is a red text, bold and right margin 25px</p>
```

2)

```
<style>
  .class1{ color:red; margin-right: 25px; font-weight:bold}
</style>

<p class="class1">this is a red text, bold and right margin 25px</p>
```

Comment: You're not going to notice a difference in speed. Choose the one that makes your code better organized and is more re-usable.

Comment: I would NOT recommend using class names like `.red` and `.right25`.  The whole point of class names is so you can change the meaning of the CSS without visiting everywhere that style is used and as soon as you do that, your style names will be incredibily misleading - messing up the whole idea for using style names.  You should be using class names like `.header` and `.product` and then assigning multiple styles to those types of names to define how you want that category of object to look.

Comment: As for the performance difference, it is likely negligible.  If you really wanted to know, you would have to create a real-world representative test and actually measure (as with all performance-related questions).  But, there are far, far more important things to optimize your code for than any likely performance delta here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how much of the code that you can actually reuse, but the performance difference won't be that big.

The biggest difference between the approaches is what the classes mean. Generally you should have classes that represent what you are trying to show, not exactly what styles you use to show it. Names that represent the intent rather than the implementation fares better when you make changes.

For example if you have the class `right25` and want to change the margins to 20 pixels instead, then you either will have a class name that doesn't represent what it actually does, or you have to change it to `right20` everywhere that you use it.

Answer (score 0):

> You're absolutely talking about the first method that could be slower than the second method?

**To answer:** There's no difference in speed of styling css.

**To illustrate:**

```
div{
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
div{
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

When css is applied over the rule, the following css will be applied by the browser:

```
div{
  color: red;/*later one*/
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;/*padding-left 5px is taken from later rule*/
}
```

And which is parsed by the browser at the same time when the div gets styled from the stylesheet.

**Why there's no difference?**

In any other programming language like JavaScript if one line gets error then another line doesn't run and so from that line of code the interpreter won't go to read the whole code.

But in css language there's no problem even if you write rules whether html has no such classes or id, there's no problem reading next line of code even if you have some mistakes in your stylesheet, whatsoever the browser will load entire stylesheet file and read the code and gives the output in same time (when stylesheet is fully loaded) and both of your code doesn't seem to be any difference in the speed.

<sub>By the way, it could be slower (that even you can't catch with your eyes) where there is slower internet connection below 32kbps because of stylesheet downloaded the line by line of code.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Two is your answer. The browser reads each class from right to left. Reading one class is faster than reading two classes.

http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Use the external stlye sheet. The browser can cache that.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp